# How to print logs into file in console application in Qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, logging

I've created in Qt creator Non-Qt project - Plain C++ application and 
I want to write some information about called functions in my log file:

for example, program invokes function

```
void my_function()
{
   WriteLogs(" some data ");
}
```

and in log file I want to see

```
my_function some_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
  printf("%s : %s",__func__, "some data");
```

You may have a slight variation depending on your compiler.